# What is considered normal ramp up for a senior developer?

Tags: software-industry, communication, new-job, united-states, developer

About a month ago I started a new job at a smallish company.  I've been a web developer for about 6 years and only worked in big companies, big enough to be listed on the stock exchange, for example.

At this new job I have immediately been given large, complex features to work on with little to no guidance and virtually no KT about the code base or business model.

All the developers seem super busy and somewhat elitist about the code.  When I've asked questions in slack I usually get an answer in the form of "that's really not too difficult" or "I'm too busy right now."  The team seems fairly defensive and negative as well.

I and the rest of the devs have been given a deadline for a major to-market release and aside from other people's feelings that it's not realistic, it's doesn't seem realistic for me because I am still very new and learning the code base as well as process.

Since I've never worked for such a small company, is this normal?  If so, what can I do to better level set expectations with my boss and the team as to what I can do given X amount of time without seeming like I'm incompetent or unwilling (both not the case).

Comment: If you find yourself needing assistance from your coworkers to proceed or be productive but they're unwilling to help you, that's something you can / should speak to your manager about.

Comment: You are not really asking a question we can help with.  If I told you normal was about 40 working days (2 months) to get to productive speed would that be helpful to you if your team expects you to be up to speed in 20?

Comment: Are your questions show stoppers or something you can pile away until the standup meeting?

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings is right.  This will vary from shop to shop.  VTC

Comment: 20 years as a developer and worked for tiny (one room 4 guys) to big (thousands spread over many towns) and the problem is not of size but of organization. Getting from a environment where you got good  documentation and one was (ahead of time) assigned to part time help and give you a overview is different from being throw in the middle of a chaos where everybody is too busy fighting fires and managent expects you to join jump in the fight in the hot of the battle is a shock

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings well I once got told "haven't you learnt that yet after 3 days" - a map reduce based system in the 80's :-)  would say a couple of weeks

Comment: @Neuromancer - I was once moved off a project after 1 week because when asked if I understood how everything worked, I asked why there were over 120000 stored procedures with no way to track how they were being called or used.  I was told that made them feel like I was not skilled enough to handle that project.  I didnt argue otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

### There is no normal.

I've been in a great number of shops, and the variance between expectations can be extreme. Some will expect a developer with a fresh diploma to follow easily the rhythm of the veterans. Others will recruit only veterans and expect them to need one year to be fully operational.

There is no normal; there are different levels of expectations, linked to the local culture, to past experiences (some have been spoiled by ultra-efficient newbies, some have been traumatized by a long streak of inefficient veterans), to current constraints (a team used to giving time might be under heavy pressure for reasons, and ask more to the newcomer just because it needs more out of him/her).

In the specific case of other developers being busy, try to narrow the questions you'll ask them, and to identify when they are more available, to disturb them less. If you reach them with accurate questions like "I see the totals are split in categories 0, 1, 2, 3, but could not find the meaning of those categories", you'll be welcomed more warmly than if you ask "how do the totals work?"

Comment: yep, everything from "hit the ground running" to "Six months to get all permissions required for access"

Comment: @TheSnarkKnight sometimes both of them at the same time... :)

Comment: I didn't realize so many of my coworkers were on SO right now

Comment: @JuhaUntinen you are **not** kidding

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up documentation for new developers (and developers switching to areas of the project with which they are unfamiliar) such as a Confluence instance. This way, you can make requests for people to help you fill in the blanks in documentation that needs to be written.

I'm doubt everyone will gleefully start contributing, but if you explain the benefits to management, and get their buy-in, it might help not only yourself, but the rest of the team.

Comment: I think under normal circumstances that would be a great idea but in this specific scenario where they're on a deadline that they're already probably going to miss for a to-market release it is a little unrealistic.

Comment: It's a very small shop, setting up a comprehensive confluence page is probably not their top priority.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the wrong question.  There is no normal.  At your current company it is what it is.

If you think you cannot meet your deadline you need to tell your boss now. If you think guidance will fix that then tell them.  If you need to offload and get guidance then tell them.